# delete row in Gridview after databind()

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

DataSource has been provided to gridview as shown below and it works fine

```
dummyGridview.DataSource = dtUser; //dtUser is DataTable
dummyGridview.DataBind();
```

Now without `OnRowDeleting` command, Is it possible to delete any particular row from Gridview based on `DataKeyNames` just after the `Databind()`?

Comment: Why not just delete the row from the DataTable before you bind?

Comment: because it will reduce my complexity otherwise I need to check many conditions

Comment: @ElGavilan yes you are right, i didn't thought of doing this way. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be good if you remove that particular row from your `DataTable` first and then bind to `gridview` as shown below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtUser.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //check 
    if(dtUser.Rows[i]["DataKeyName"].ToString()) == yourValue))
    {
        //remove
        dtUser.Rows.Remove(dtUser.Rows[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

then

```
dummyGridview.DataSource = dtUser;
dummyGridview.DataBind();
```

Hope It solves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove more than 1 row from the datatable you can use the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dtUser.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dtUser.Rows[i]["DataKeyName"] == req.value)
    {
        dtUser.Rows.Remove(dtUser.Rows[i]);
        i--;
    }
}
```

after that you can bind the database